# How to import default export type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to declare window.lottie with the below code.

```js
// node_modules/lottie-web/index.d.ts
type LottiePlayer = {
    play(name?: string): void;
    stop(name?: string): void;
    setSpeed(speed: number, name?: string): void;
    setDirection(direction: AnimationDirection, name?: string): void;
    searchAnimations(animationData?: any, standalone?: boolean, renderer?: string): void;
    loadAnimation(params: AnimationConfigWithPath | AnimationConfigWithData): AnimationItem;
    destroy(name?: string): void;
    registerAnimation(element: Element, animationData?: any): void;
    setQuality(quality: string | number): void;
    setLocationHref(href: string): void;
};

declare const Lottie: LottiePlayer;

export default Lottie;
```

```
//src/type.d.ts
import Lottie from 'lottie-web';

declare interface Window {
  lottie: Lottie;
}
```

But there is an error.

```
TS2749: 'Lottie' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

So how to import default export type in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`declare const Lottie:LottiePlayer` tells us that module `lottie-web` exports an **object** of type `LottiePlayer`, **not** a type.

It looks like you really want `window.lottie` to be of type `LottiePlayer`.

The type `LottiePlayer` is not explicitly exported from `lottie-web`. However, using the `typeof` keyword, we can sidestep this as follows:

```
import Lottie from 'lottie-web';

declare interface Window {
  lottie: typeof Lottie; //LottiePlayer
}
```